# Prevent Spamming of button to call function

Tags: jquery, html

How can I prevent Spamming of button on calling a function?? like the user can only call the function every 1 sec on the button.

Is there a way doing it?? cause I tried setTimeout but it didnt works it still spamming
BTW i used Jquery.

here is my code:

```
<button class="buttonUpdateStatus" id="idbuttonUpdateStatus" onclick="alertStatus()">Post Status</button>



 function alertStatus() {
        $('#doneStatus').hide();
        $('#loadingStatus').show();
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can lock (prevent the function logic from execution) the function in the following way:

```
var locked = false;
function alertStatus () {
    if (!locked) {
        locked = true;
        setTimeout(unlock, 1000);
        $('#doneStatus').hide();
        $('#loadingStatus').show();
    }
}

function unlock () {
    locked = false;
}
```

You can also disable the button such that the user cannot click it at all:

```
function alertStatus () {
    $('#idbuttonUpdateStatus').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(enable, 1000);
    $('#doneStatus').hide();
    $('#loadingStatus').show();
}

function enable () {
    $('#idbuttonUpdateStatus').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Comment: This is a really nice method. I actually combined both of these methods just in case someone re-enabled the disabled buttons via firebug or etc(which works), although I know its unlikely. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent the calling of a function in your web page.  If hackers want to mess with the code in your page, they can.

If you want to block the frequent calling of an ajax function by a particular client, then you will have to do that on the server using techniques like client login, rate limiting, etc...

---

If you want to just prevent a normal mouse click from pressing the button more than once within a given time period, that's pretty easy.  You just disable the button when it is pressed and only enable it again some time later.

Answer (score 0):

How about this little Plug-In for JQuery to debounce if i'm right: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

I like konstantin's solution, but It doesn't really prevent spamming as the button will still be clicked every 1000ms if spamming goes on for a long time. For my need, it was better to launch the code only when the user is done with the spamming. So I came up with this solution:

```
var timerId;

function _doActionNoSpam() {
    //Reset Timeout if function is called before it ends
    if (!(timerId == null)) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
    }
    timerId = setTimeout(function () {
        //Place code that you don't want to get spammed here
    }, 400); //400ms Timeout
    //Place code that can be spammed here (UI updates, etc)
};
```

I placed the code inside the Timeout so that it's execution can be cancelled if the button is clicked again to soon. This can be useful, for exemple,  if you have a "next day" button that makes a big call to a database everytime it is clicked. In this situation, the user might want to quickly click the button to move the date to next week. Only the last click is really usefull to him, so the call to the database would be make only once at the end.

Please note that this will introduce a small delay between the click and the execution of your code when the user only click the button once. So make sure to keep the Timeout low (400ms in my exemple)