# JQuery - How to deal with field that can be updated via arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just discovered a problem on my shoping cart page and am unsure of the best way to deal with this.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and have been working on the quantity fields in the shopping basket. When a user increases (via click) the amount, it automatically updates the cart information.

Now while testing this I mistakenly dragged my mouse over the quantity field and I noticed that the value increases if I slide over it, or if I use the arrow keys... and obviously my current jquery function does not pick up on this:

Here is the current code:

```
 $('.product-quantity').on('click','.input-group',function(){
    //Do stuff
}
```

So my question is this, what would be a better way to deal with the changing quantity field so that no matter what method is used to update the value, it triggers the function?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the onchange event :

```
$('.product-quantity').on('change','.input-group',function(){
    //Do stuff
}
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onchange)

Comment: Thanks - another issue I just noticed, whats the best way to deal with "flooding", if I for instance, slide the quantity up from 1 to say 20, the form incrementally calls the ajax script for each quantity change so 20 times (Which is pretty slow)... is there a way to prevent this from happening or a method to deal with this type of problem?

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963687/prevent-spamming-of-button-to-call-function

You can try to set a timeout on the function called